# How to write a pop function for a stack in Javascript/Typescript in O(1)

Tags: javascript, typescript, data-structures, stack

I am trying to build my own stack in TypeScript and I am having trouble implementing a pop() function that can run in O(1) time complexity to mimic Javascript's native pop() function. I am able to delete the top-most item, but Javascript keeps the index in the stack as `undefined`. To combat this, I filter the stack to remove undefined, causing O(n) time complexity. Any other ideas to implement this in O(1) is appreciated. Current code:

```
public pop(): T {
        if (this.isEmpty()) {
            throw new Error('Empty Stack');
        }
        const popped = this.storage[this.size() - 1];
        this.stackSize--;
        delete (this.storage[this.size() - 1]);
        this.storage = this.storage.filter(x => x !== undefined);
        return popped;
    }
```

Comment: What type is `this.storage`, is it an array? If yes, why not use `this.storage.pop()` instead of `delete`?

Comment: ```this.storage``` is an array, but I am trying to achieve the same results as the native .pop() function without actually using it, rather making it myself. I am using ```delete``` to remove the top value of the stack from the array without using pop.

Comment: Why do you have `size()` when there is `length`. It is strange that you *don't* want to use `pop` or `length` (seemingly), but are happy to use (it seems) `filter` which is a higher level function than `pop`. I don't see the consistency here.

Comment: *"but Javascript keeps the index in the stack as undefined"*: this is not true, the index is no longer present. Sure, if you try to output the corresponding value, you'll get `undefined`, but that is also true for any other index that was never defined.

Comment: @trincot If I create a stack with 1,2,3 pushed, and I console.log() the stack, `Stack: {"storage": [1,2,3],}` will return. If I then call `pop()` and console.log() the stack again, I am left with `Stack: {"storage": [1,2,undefined],}`. And regarding your previous question, I know `filter` is higher level, and I do not want to use it, it's just there as a placeholder for now until I can achieve the functionality of the native pop.

Comment: Yes, it will print like that, but that `undefined` is not a *stored* value. It is the absence of value and it is printed because `length` is still what it was. I don't understand why you want to mimic an array behaviour, and use an array for that. If you truly want to implement array features yourself, then don't use an array, but only a plain object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can shorten the array like this:

```js
this.storage.length = this.storage.length-1
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't  need to actually remove the item from the array

if you simply call

```
this.stackSize--;
```

you implicitly say that you removed it

the thing is that you need to change all of your other functions to work with index instead of native functions

so the top()
should be like

```js
top(){

return this.stack[this.stackSize-1]
}
```

and so on...

This will achieve O(1)

Comment: The problem with this is that even using index, when I remove the top item in the stack and adjust the ```stackSIze``` length, javascript still keeps the index in the array and just assigns it a value of ```undefined```. Returning the top value of the stack isn't the problem, but removing the index from my stack is what is giving me trouble without using native functions.